# How to Extract subject Verb Object using NLP Java? for every sentence

Tags: stanford-nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech, simplenlg

I want to find a **subject, verb, and object** for each sentence and then it will be passed to natural language generation library **simpleNLG** to form a sentence.

I tried multiple libraries like **Cornlp, opennlp, Standford parsers**. But I can not find them accurately.

Now in the worst case, I will have to write a long set of if-else to find subject, verb, and object form each sentence which is not always accurate for simpleNLG

like,

- NN, nsub etc goes to subject, VB, VBZ goes to verb.

**I tried lexical parser**,

```
LexicalizedParser lp = **new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz");**
String[] sent = { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
parse.pennPrint();
System.out.println();
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
tp.print(parse);
```

**which gives this output,**

```
nsubj(use-2, I-1)
root(ROOT-0, use-2)
det(parser-4, a-3)
dobj(use-2, parser-4)
```

**And I want something like this**

```
subject = I
verb = use
det = a
object = parser
```

***Is there a simpler way to find this in JAVA or should I go with if-else? please help me with it.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `openie` annotator to get triples.  You can run this at the command line or build a pipeline with these annotators.

command:

```
java -Xmx10g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,natlog,openie -file example.txt
```

Java:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,natlog,openie");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Annotation result = pipeline.process("...");
```

input:

```
Joe ate some pizza.
```

output:

```
Extracted the following Open IE triples:
1.0     Joe     ate     pizza
```

More details here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html

Comment: I came across oepnIE but it requires minimum of 5gb memory to run the program, is there any way to run it on lower memory?

And also will it work on complex sentences?

Comment: You can remove ner annotator and I am able to run it with 2G of RAM